Assistance Needed for Updating Locked Metadata Due to Duplicate/Spoof Token Issue
Hello Solana Community,
We are facing an issue with our Kenji Meme Token that we just found out after troubleshooting many issues. We found out that shortly after minting, a duplicate/spoof token was created using the same name and image, causing warnings about potential spoofing on platforms such as SolExplorer. I did not create the second one. We used PinkSale to create the token and launch and I am not into development, just reaching out to see what can be done.
Details:
Our Token Mint Address: 7WMvPvfsgacSvCtSwoPwJz5PgZWwPFC3L8E3zXWZQfwL
Our Mint Timestamp: May 11, 2024, 00:51:48 +UTC
Duplicate Token Mint Address: 645FXyjtChzZegM117WUrDLHujHk9WBmRJFZ2Hno9x6n
Duplicate Mint Timestamp: May 11, 2024, 00:52:34 +UTC
Prepared Actions:
Prepared reports for SolExplorer and SolScan to address the duplicate token issue.
Request for Help:
Can we reach out for support to have our locked metadata updated to change the image and other details to distinguish our token from the duplicate?
Are there specific steps or contacts within the Solana ecosystem that can assist with this metadata update?
Thank you for your guidance and support.
Best regards,
Arturo Roman,
CEO
Kenji Meme

do you have the authority keypair that created the token?

We minted through Pinksale and I am not sure if the pair can be found in the dashboard on there or if we'd have to go to their directly to ask for the pair. Unfortunately the only support they have is on Telegram and we are in a team chat with them and it can be hard to get responses from them or have them understand us.

I can share the code to do this but you would need the authority keypair for the token.

We have reached out to Pinksale, the responses:
Keypair?
look mate duplicate tokens are normal in solana
stop stressing out
this is something that happens to most coins
with or without authority would still happen
nobody can unrenounce it now
you cannot take it back
sadly blockchain is immutable
just ignore fake tokens, there are other showing too
what warning?
i don’t see any problems
(showed the Solana Explorer and not showing logo)
he said: it’s not solscan
...that was it..So now we have a duplicate with our image and we have no logo and shows SPL token on Solscan

So he basically said this is normal, nothing can be done. Spoofs are done all the time, it is renounced and can't be fixed. Yet we will forever have no logo due to a bot making a token a minute after us. So @Jimii can it actually be done with what he is saying?

concerning the token spoofing, yes, it is normal. Concerning the metadata change, unless the is mutable field is set to false, then it is possible to change. But you would need the wallet keypair that created the token to do so.

yeah isMutable: 0 . I have read in certain circumstances that Solana itself can intervene or Metaplex to help in special cases. So I am guessing we will never have an image for the token since the spoofed one got ours first, unless at some point it will show up, but I don't think so since it has been renounced for weeks.
